# Пояснение, уточнение - как их определить в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, правила

Пожалуйста, расскажите поподробнее об уточнении и пояснении и как их вообще определить в предложении? Желательно на простом языке.

Спасибо.

Comment: Это не тот вопрос, на который дают «верный» ответ в одну-две  фразы. Читайте, к примеру, здесь: https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724v

Answer (score 3):

Логическую основу ***пояснительных*** отношений составляет мысль о тождестве (совпадении, равенстве, соответствии). Чаще всего работает союз ТО ЕСТЬ:

*Такие дикие яблоки у нас зовут лешовками, предполагая, что леший, то есть тайный хозяин леса, выращивает их для себя* (Сол.) Здесь ***леший = хозяин леса***.

***Уточняющие*** отношения - это ограничение, конкретизация, дополняюще-уточняющее значение. При уточнении значение как бы сужается.

*На углу, возле почты, была фотографическая витрина (Бун.).*

Если хотите разобраться в тонкостях, прочитайте статьи [Уточнение](http://scicenter.online/sintaksis-scicenter/utochnenie-126427.html)  и [Пояснение](http://scicenter.online/sintaksis-scicenter/poyasnenie-126425.html) Ответ составлен на их основе.